# How can I both conditionally log on exit status and pass it through in shell?

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I have a code module in which I will be checking for errors using the "$?" in shell scripting. Assume the following scenario:

```
"sub_script.sh"// I have invalid host name inside this file
--error statements--


"Main.sh"
sh -x sub_script.sh >> $LOGFILE
if [ $? -eq 0 ];
then
 echo "error"
else
 echo "no error"
fi
```

Now, even if I have error statements in the sub_script.sh if I trigger the script from the main_script.sh I can't handle it because I have an echo statement which runs successfully and returns 0 value.

I just replicated this here I have many shell scripts which run a hive or spark or some other code.

Is there any change to handle this kind of scenario in shell scripting?

Comment: Note that `sh -x ./anything` is generally a bad practice. It means that `anything`'s shebang is ignored, instead of being used to select the interpreter to use, so you can't write your scripts for a non-`sh` interpreter (bash, ksh, etc -- or swap the scripts out for compiled executables without modifying the callers) as you otherwise could.

Comment: The best way to handle this is to not do this sort of thing.  `if [ $? -eq 0 ]` is almost always bad practice.  If you simply ended your script with `sh -x sub_script.sh` and let the sub_script print usable error messages, your problem would be solved.  If you really need to check it, you should do `if sh -x sub_script.sh; then ...; else exit 1; fi` . Wrapping commands and printing vague error messages is *always* a bad idea.

Comment: Typically it is considered success when `$?` -eq 0, so printing `error` seems odd in that case.

Comment: And if you are going to print `error`, it really feels like an error message.  As such, it belongs on stderr: `echo "error" >&2`

Answer (score 0):

When you want to pass through an exit status, record it. If you're going to do this over and over, a function helper can be useful:

```
#!/bin/sh

retval=0
recording_errors() {
  # local is not strictly POSIX syntax, but honored in dash and others.
  local local_retval >/dev/null 2>&1 ||:
  "$@"; local_retval=$?                # run our arguments as a command
  retval=$(( retval | local_retval ))  # OR the result into global exit status
  return "$local_retval"               # then return that local exit status.
}

if recording_errors ./sub_script; then
  echo "success running sub_script"
else
  echo "failure running sub_script"
fi

exit "$retval"
```

With that construction, you can run several tasks and track whether any of them failed:

```
recording_errors thing_a || echo "WARNING: thing_a failed with status $?" >&2
recording_errors thing_b || echo "WARNING: thing_b failed with status $?" >&2
exit "$retval"   # exit with the combination of both thing_a and thing_b retval
```